# Jquery validate plugin two buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using an awesome plugin to validate my form on the front-end: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation .  The problem is the form has two buttons (back and submit).  I can bypass the back button from validating the form using the  css class cancel, thanks to the plugin; but the other js still fires (the animated gif, disable the submit button, and the change of opacity to the submit). DARN.

I tried wrapping the entire thing in a click function for submitbtn, so that back button wouldn't have anything to do with it, that didn't work. I also tried putting just the back button in a click function that would reverse style effects, that didn't work.

I seek the advice of a smarter man, or woman, thanks!

```
$(".simple_form").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $(".submitbtn").addClass("opacitychangeonsubmit"); // change submit button opacity
        $(".submitbtn").attr("disabled", true);// disable the submit btn
        $('#loading_image').show(); // show animated gif
        form.submit();
    }
})
```

Comment: Could I check somewhere for the class back and return false before?

Comment: Can you change the "back" button to `type='button'` instead of `type='submit'`?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately won;t work in this scenario :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went a different route, which is somewhat ugly and hackish, although working just fine.

```
$(".simple_form").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {

        if ((form.elements.item(10).value) == "Back") {
            form.submit();
        } else {
            $(".submitbtn").addClass("opacitychangeonsubmit"); // change submit button opacity
            $(".submitbtn").attr("disabled", true);// disable the submit btn
            $('#loading_image').show(); // show animated gif
            form.submit();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting everything but `form.submit();` in the 'success' callback.

```
$(".simple_form").validate({
  success: function() {
    $(".submitbtn").addClass("opacitychangeonsubmit"); // change submit button opacity
    $(".submitbtn").attr("disabled", true);// disable the submit btn
    $('#loading_image').show(); // show animated gif
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
  }
});
```

The idea is to hilight form as inactive only if validation was successful and form was actually submitted.

Comment: Almost, but the animated gif fires now even if the form didn't validate, so it's still going when you fix the errors. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Make sure there is no left-over bindings, some `click` for example,  that's showing the loader image

Comment: Nothing it's firing from the  $('#loading_image').show(); // show animated gif

Comment: Could I check if the button has the class back and return false at the beginning of my code?